# Assign additional/virtual MAC address/interface on Win 10

Tags: windows, networking, windows-10, mac, ip

I have the frustrating scenation at my university that they supply static IP addresses via MAC address.

When I register my computer with my MAC in my apartment I get an IP from a specific address range. When I come to the office, I get a random IP address assigned because it is not in the same network.

Now the policy is that every MAC address can only be registered once for a static IP address. I would need to decide if I want a static IP at home or at the office. But I want a static IP address at both locations and I do not want to assign static addresses or use scripts.

Which options do I have?

- Is it possible to somewhat assign two MAC addresses to an interface (an alias)? Likely not.
- Maybe a bridge of some sort is a solution?
- I could definitely install a tap device and bridge this with my ethernet interface but this I would like to avoid if there are better (and importantly, built-in) options.

Answer (score 3):

1. Enable the Hyper-V feature in Win10 and build a VM.
2. Configure an external virtual switch.
3. Navigate to the Device Manager in the VM, and change the network address in the NIC properties.

[image: Screenshot of the Advanced NIC properties tab]

Comment: This looks primising. To make sure - this requires a VM to be up and running?